# How to configure nginx for websocket. I have django for REST in backend. The standard configurations i found over net wont work for nginx websocket

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx to server to browser. I want nginx to serve for websocket requests from browser. Nginx has internally proxy to django (gunicorn uwsgi) using proxy configs. I am not able to set up the config in nginx for websocket. Tried different configs from internet but no success. My default file in nginx config file :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /usr/share/gmc/dist;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 /index.html index.js;
        }
        location ~ /redfish.* {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139470/cant-use-nginx-as-websocket-proxy/49146542#49146542

Answer (score 0):

These are the basic settings you need to apply for your django-project:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name **Server Name or IP**;

 #Website LOGO:
 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}

 #Static Files like CSS, JS
 location = /static/ {
       root /home/hitshell/website/project/
 }

 #Media Files like Images, Videos etc.
 location = /media/ {
       root /home/hitshell/website/project/
 }

 #proxy
 location = / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/hitshell/website/project/project.sock;
    }
 }
```

**REFERENCE:**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn

https://www.shellvoide.com/hacks/installing-django-application-with-nginx-mysql-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-vps/

The First one has some missing configurations in the middle of the tutorial.